# Server won't connect to network

Tags: networking, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-server

First of all, sorry for not being better with informations, bu I have literally no idea what is wrong here, and thus no idea what data to post.

I have had a server running for some time now without problems, but after having it moved it suddenly will no longer connect to the network.

I am using the exact same setup as before (including cabels) but clearly something broke.

The server is running Ubuntu server 18.04.1 and have this board https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/atom/x10/a1sri-2758f.cfm

So. What info do I need to post to make this question answerable?

Comment: Is that server connected to a switch? Did moving the server involve changing the port of the switch where the server is connected?

Comment: It is connected to a Linksys X3000. I do not remember what port it was connected to though.

Comment: OK, but what about the second part of my question?

Comment: Sorry, wanted to make a linebreak but posted instead. As mentioned (in edit) I don't remember which port it was connected to, I can try the others out though if you think it will help

Comment: If you didn't try yet, this for sure would be a good thing. It would not be the first switch where only one certain port is not working (for example, due to dust). You could also look at the LEDs which designate Ethernet activity / status, at the server side and the switch side.

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned that. The LED are blinking in both ends, but the server doesn't show up on the list of connected devices, and running ifconfig doesn't return an IP address

Comment: Then your switch is obviously more a router, and it seems that it includes a DHCP server (I don't know the Zyxel device you mentioned). So the next thing I would try is setting a static IP address in your Ubuntu server (just in case that it can't get an IP address via DHCP). That static address of course must not be already assigned to another device in your network and must be part of your subnet.

Comment: Tried it. No luck.

Comment: Could you put a separate NIC into the server and use that to connect to your network (just for testing)?